# AWS Glue Crawler S3 include / exclude patterns

Tags: amazon-s3, glob, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I am having trouble describing the path of .csv files in an S3 bucket to build an AWS Glue table to query with AWS Athens.

The path of the data files are:

```
/bucket-name/YYYY/MM/DD/CC/CC-YYYY-MM-DD.csv

e.g.: 
/bucket-name/2019/01/01/AR/AR-2019-01-01.csv
/bucket-name/2019/01/01/TR/TR-2019-01-01.csv
...
/bucket-name/2019/01/02/AR/AR-2019-01-02.csv
/bucket-name/2019/01/02/TR/TR-2019-01-02.csv
...
```

where YYYY, MM and DD are the elements of the date and CC is the country code.

Among them, I want to pick only the files for a specific country to build the table.

The folders also contain temporary files in the form

```
/bucket-name/YYYY/MM/DD/CC/hhmm.csv
e.g. 
/bucket-name/2019/01/01/AR/0001.csv
/bucket-name/2019/01/01/AR/0002.csv
/bucket-name/2019/01/01/TR/0001.csv
/bucket-name/2019/01/01/TR/0002.csv
...
```

which I want to exclude from the Glue table.

I tried to use glob patterns in the include path such that:

```
s3://bucket-name/2019/??/??/TR/TR-*.csv
```

No tables are created after the crawler running for 8 minutes! for a small dataset.

After concluding that the glob patterns are not allowed in the include path, I tried to use the exclude patterns with negation to specify include patterns:

```
include path: s3://bucket-name/2019/
exclude patterns: [!-TR]
```

This did not work as expected:

- the results did include countries with T, not only TR
- the temporary files of the format .../0001.csv are not excluded (I'd expect so because of the [!-] exclude pattern)
- it created separate files, although I've specified the "Create
  a single schema for each S3 path" option
- the process exited with an "Internal Service Exception" after creating a few tables
- the tables do not return any data in the Athena preview, although the Glue table details state that there are object in them

So;

Are the glob patterns not allowed in the include path?

If not, how can I achieve the same thing with exclude patterns?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You said "the results did include countries with T, not only TR", thats because your pattern is wrong. To exclude .CSV files starting with TR you should use ```**/!(TR*).csv```